# Tengo python 3.8 y necesito usar el 3.6 (windows)

Tags: python-3.x, windows

sucede que necesito la librería Pattern que tiene errores de compatibilidad con python 3.8 (me lanza error "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration" y según ví sucede por la versión 3.8 de python. Lo probé en un entorno virtual 3.6 y funciona bien.
La cuestión es que en windows ya tengo instalado el 3.8
Hay alguna forma de instalar otra versión del 3? o tengo que borrar el 3.8?
En caso de poder instalarla, cómo se ejecuta sin producir incompatibilidades?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instalar la versión que necesitas y desde tu editor de código puedes elegir la versión con la que quieres compilar tu proyecto y así te evitas el tema de la desintalación.

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace? Porque el entorno virtual me lo crea en la misma versión de python. No encuentro cómo escribir el código para elegir la versión de python necesaria

Comment: 1. Instala la versión que deseas de python.
2. Ejemplo: con visual studio code en la parte inferior izquierda aparece la versión con la que se está compilando, das click y ahí te aparecen las otras versiones que necesitas, seleccionas y ya está listo